# Trouble working with helper on handlebars + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use helpers, but I get this error: `ReferenceError: a is not defined`

I'm trying to display home.hbs under the views dir. because it contains things like:

```
 <li class="{{#if_eq title "Home"}}active{{/if_eq}}">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
 </li>
```

this is the **app.js**

```
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');

// Handlebars configuration

app.engine('hbs', hbs({
  extname: 'hbs',
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, '/views/layouts/'),
  partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, '/views/partials/'),
  helpers: {
    if_eq: function () {
      if (a == b) {
        return opts.fn(this);
      } else {
        return opts.inverse(this);
      }
    },
    getStringifiedJson: function (value) {
      return JSON.stringify(value);
    }
  }
}));


app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

I've trying using the handlebars docs but it seems like there are so many versions on NPM, like hbs, express-handlebars, exphbs. I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no argument in the function. Hence the error. This should work

```
if_eq: function (a, b, options) {
      if (a == b) {
        return opts.fn(this);
      } else {
        return opts.inverse(this);
      }
}
```